# Angular2 service doesn't return result to Observable from http.get to component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use a get to set a view in angular2.
A hava a component and a service

in the template I have a seachbutton, that fires the search funtion on the component

```
//component
searchResult : SearchData[];
searchData(){
    this.search.geSearchResultPart1(this.form.searchterm)
        .subscribe(
            searchresult => {
                    this.searchResult = searchresult
                    console.log(  searchresult ); // undefined
                }, 
                err => {
                   console.log(err);
                });
}
```

In the service i do

```
 getSearchResultPart1(searchWord : string) : Observable<SearchData[]> {
    let fullURL = 'url=http://domain.nl/searchData.php?q='+searchWord;     
    return this.http.get(fullURL)
        .map((res: Response) => { 
            res.json().data as SearchData[]
            console.log(res.json()); // Shows an array with objects
        })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

I also included (and the necessary other imports)

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

The service does show response on the console.log, but it doesn't return the data.
I searched and followed multiple tuts, but no result. I think i am doing it wright, but forgetting a small thing, but i don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `=>` with `{}` you need to explicitly `return`

```
return this.http.get(fullURL)
    .map((res: Response) => { 
        res.json().data as SearchData[]
        console.log(res.json()); // Shows an array with objects
        return res.json();
    })
```

Comment: Thanks,  first i wrote it whiteout {} but that didn't work on the component. So i added the log to check the response and forgot the response. I will accept your answer in 2 minutes.